# Ruby activerecord result to array

Tags: ruby, activerecord

My aim is to take the result of my activerecord search and print it into a nice array but the print part is where I am having trouble.

I first build my oracle connection with the following which works in isolation.

```
  def oracle_connection(adapter, database, username, password)
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
          adapter: adapter,
          database: database,
          username: username,
          password: password)
    end
  end
```

I then create my query with the following function:

```
def query
      "select * from owner.appn where appn_id = #{$id}"
end
```

And here is the part where I am asking the question on. I want to pass the result of the query being returned out into an 2D array. Below is what I currently have to execute the active connection query.

```
  def oracle_query_into_array(query)
    result_set = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
    if result_set.present?
#add logic here
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have reasons to use the underlying connection calls rather than the abstractions that are common practise.

With the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)` I would expect this to return true if it executes. What you want is a cursor on the data, so try this:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query)
puts result.to_a
=> [array of results]
```

A usual abstraction ([ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)) would take the form of creating a model to represent your data, so in your case, this could look like:

```
class Appn < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This will be automatically mapped to a table within your connection called Appnn allowing you to update the above code to:

```
results = Appn.where(appn_id: $id)
puts results.to_a
=> [array of results]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you edit your response to give me an example of how the abstraction would work with the connection calls in the context of above? This is only day 3 of my Ruby so the better behaviour steer would be more appreciated